# 415 Unsupported Media Type with Spring MVC and Rest Service

Tags: spring, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, angularjs-scope

I am getting

```
415 Unsupported Media Type - The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method
```

Request URL is:

```
http://localhost:8080/ngdemo/web/posts/review/80a5d7660cdb82a8ef9f8db79bb3c8ab14555377
```

error while reading from spring controller; I checked with my other controller methods of same pattern and they are working fine but not this one which I newly introduced. I cant find any issue with it, can you please suggest whats I am missing?

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/review/{key}", method = RequestMethod.GET,  consumes = "", produces = "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
List<Review> reviews(@PathVariable(value = "key") String key) {
    System.out.println("key : " + key);

    List<Review> reviewList = reviewService.getReviewsById(key);

    System.out.println("reviewList : " + reviewList.size());

    return reviewList;
}
```

My Services.js of Angular:

```
services.factory('PostFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
alert("I am here service");

return  {

    postmain: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: {method: 'POST'}
    }),
    reviews: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts/review/:key', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {key: '@key'} },
        create: {method: 'POST'}
    }),
    postreview: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts/getreview', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: {method: 'POST'}
    }),
    allresults: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts/result/:tag', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {tag: '@tag'} },
        create: {method: 'POST'}
    })};
```

}]);

Code in my controller.js which makea call:

```
var reviewId = place.id;
$scope.allreviews = PostFactory.reviews.query({key: reviewId})
```

I cant find where the issue is, so can you guys please have a look and point me what is that which I missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by adding:

```
 @Consumes("text/html")

 @Consumes("text/html")
@RequestMapping(value = "/review/{key}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =   "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
List<Review> reviews(@PathVariable(value = "key") String key) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is your `consumes` parameter set to `""`?

If:

- you delete `consumes = "",` from your mapping
- JSON is properly configured in your app (the defaults should be fine)
- your client application sends the proper `Content-Type` HTTP Header

Then it should work.

Comment: Sorry, it was not working without consumes as well, I just added it to check if works! It was not working without as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the network tab, first you need to confirm if Angular are sending the parameter in the url, probably your request are send the information on the request payload.

The error 415 is erro to convert information. @PathVariable is a annotation to get parameter inside the url:

https://stackoverflow.com/{pathVariableParam}/

Create an object and insert it in the method using a annotation @RequestBody

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/review", method = RequestMethod.GET,  consumes = "", produces = "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody List<Review> reviews(@RequestBody String key) { // Or (@RequestBody ObjectKey key)
System.out.println("key : " + key);

List<Review> reviewList = reviewService.getReviewsById(key);

System.out.println("reviewList : " + reviewList.size());

return reviewList;
```

}

Comment: No, it didnt work by changing to @RequestBody; in question I have mentioned key value is been passed in the localhost url shown above. this is response header:  Content-Language en
Content-Length 949
Content-Type text/html;charset=utf-8
Date Fri, 11 Apr 2014 16:05:27 GMT
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headers
Accept application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5